# How to use joint query in this association - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working in ruby 2.1.5 and rails 3.2.1. I want to list all the company in grid which is associated to `company_name = John`

Company table:

[image]

company model:

```
has_many :partner_relationships, :class_name => "CompanyRelationship",:foreign_key => 'partner_id',
```

company_relationships table:

[image]

I want to get all the company information from company table where `company.id = partner_id`. I tried the below query

```
Company.joins(:partner_relationships).where('company_relationships.partner_id' => company.id)
```

This is returning 3 set of same data that is `<#id:2, company_name:John, description:I am John#>`

I want to return the records as follows `<#id:1, company_name:Jose, description:I am Jose#>, <#id:3, company_name:George, description:I am George#>,..<#id:5, company_name:Alwin, description:''#>`

Please help me in solving this.

Comment: parent_id and partner_id both are company.id. I want to list all company_name from company table, associated with partner_id

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use "partner_id"?

Comment: I am using partner_id, i missed to put in copy paste from notepad. I updated the question.please help me.

Comment: And company = Company.find(2)?

Comment: but what is parent_id? That should ref the company.id right? So you should use it in your foreign_key?!?

Comment: parent_id and partner_id both are company.id. I want to list all company_name from company table, associated with partner_id.

Comment: have you tried to change your foreign_key to "parent_id"?